# How to fix the 'airflow.exceptions.AirflowSensorTimeout: Snap. Time is OUT'

Tags: timeout, airflow, sensors

Sometimes for no apparent reason, we are getting an error 'airflow.exceptions.AirflowSensorTimeout: Snap. Time is OUT.'
and several DAGs fail. I'm not sure what is the origin of this error or what might resolve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

sensor times out (not to be confused with request timeout) when success condition is not met. So i will check which condition failed.